# When do we use "went bowling," and when do we use "go bowling"?

Tags: tenses, past-tense

In this dialogue what is the appropriate form?

> A: Would you like to **go bowling** with me today?
>
> B: I don't think so. To be honest, I really don't feel like **going bowling** today. I **went bowling** yesterday.
>
> A: That's too bad. I'm disappointed.
>
> B: I hope you understand, If I hadn't **gone bowling** yesterday, I'd be very happy to **go bowling** with you today.
>
> A: Of course, I understand! After all, I suppose you'd get tired of **going bowling** if you **went bowling** all the time.

In our Oral Activity, we were supposed to follow the format below:

> A: Would you like to **go on a picnic** with me today?
>
> B: I don't think so. To be honest, I really don't feel like **going on a picnic today**.  I **went on a picnic** yesterday.
>
> A: That's too bad. I'm disappointed.
>
> B: I hope you understand, If I hadn't **gone on a picnic yesterday**, I'd be very happy to **go on a picnic** with you today.
>
> A: Of course, I understand! After all, I suppose you'd get tired of **going on picnics** if you **went on picnics** all the time.

So, my question is : Was it correct to use ***went bowling*** instead of **go bowling** in the last part of the dialogue and why? Also, on the format which we needed to follow why did they use **went on picnics** instead of **go on picnics**?

Please help.

Thanks!

Comment: It's the [subjunctive mood](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subjunctive_mood#English).  B doesn't actually go bowling all the time, but A is making a statement about what *would* happen *if* B did (she'd get tired of it). It's easier to spot if you expand the contraction "You'd" into "You would".

Comment: This is not subjunctive, this is second conditional.

Answer (score 2):

The first sentence you are asking about is in the second conditional:

> I suppose you'**d** get tired of going bowling if you **went** bowling all the time.

Second conditional are if-sentences which talk about imaginary situations. It implies that you do not go bowling all the time but if you did (past tense) you would get tired of it.

You can say the same thing using the first conditional:

> I suppose you'**ll** get tired of going bowling if you **go** bowling all the time.

First conditional is real; that means in this case you really go bowling all the time and I tell you that because you do that (present tense) you will get tired of it.

The sentence about the picnics follows the exact same logic.